# libopencv_legacy.o is not found

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, image-processing

I have installed opencv as given by the instructions in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation)
 but I can't find `opencv_legacy.o` object file in the corresponding directory

```
image = imread( "/home/safar/Desktop/shakkeeb/thebss/images/pic.jpg", 1 ); 
namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imshow( "Display Image", image ); 
waitKey(0);
```

Header files included are 
`cv.h` and `highgui.h` the error was : 
 1. ‘imread’ was not declared in this scope
2. ‘namedWindow’ was not declared in this scope
3. ‘imshow’ was not declared in this scope
4. ‘waitKey’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: Can you provide some more details please. Is this a build failing that can't find it, or have you done a `find` command? If the former, can you provide what was run please and what output was.

Comment: hope the updated data will be sufficient, thank you

Comment: some failures was there. but it worked perfectly on another system

Comment: Just to be clear, the #include of cv.h is working, but the methods within cv.h are not? Try compiling with the -E flag (assuming GCC) and see if the pre-processor output is as you expect.